# Insert data after submit web_form

Tags: webforms

I'm new with Drupal and I want to save a user after submitting the form, so I create a new module with 3 files: openerp_client.info, openerp_client.module and the openerp_client.install

I want to know how to save this user in my table. This is my openerp_client.install:

```
function openerp_client_schema() {
$schema = array();
$schema['openerp_client'] = array(
'description' => 'The base table for nodes.',
'fields' => array(
  'oc_id' => array(
    'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
    'type' => 'serial',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
  ),

  'first_name' => array(
    'description' => "User's first name.",
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 32,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
  'last_name' => array(
    'description' => "User's last name.",
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 32,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
   'company' => array(
    'description' => "User's company name.",
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 32,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
   'email_address' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 254,
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'default' => '',
    'description' => "User's e-mail address.",
  ),
),
'indexes' => array(
  'openerp_client_oc_id' => array('oc_id'),
),

'primary key' => array('oc_id'),
);
return $schema;
}
```

This is what's in my implementation of `hook_webform_submission_insert()`:

```
function openerp_client_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) { 
$nid = db_insert('openerp_client')
 ->fields(array(
'first_name' => $submission->first_name,
'last_name' =>$submission->last_name, 
'company' =>$submission->company, 
'email_address' =>$submission->email_address,
))
->execute();
}
```

But I get this exception:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {openerp_client} (first_name, last_name, company, email_address) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => ...

Why?

Comment: [Database API](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database). Please read that first, and come back if you have a _specific_ question about code you've written yourself

Comment: Thanks, i get this error :
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {openerp_client} (first_name, last_name, company, email_address) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => ...

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jemai, I've edited the exception into your question too. Short answer: `$submission->first_name` is empty

Comment: Thanks Clive, but i insert the first_name in my form befor submitting

Comment: Not disputing that - but by the time scope reaches your webform hook, `$submission->first_name` is empty. It's the only possible explanation for the PDO error you see

Comment: @JemaiHamza did you debug `$submission` argument? is it returning anything?

Comment: @xurshid29 : `stdClass Object ( [nid] => 1 [uid] => 1 [submitted] => 1397487126 [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1 [is_draft] => 0 [data] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => test ) ) [2] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => test ) ) [3] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => test ) ) [4] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => test@mail.fr ) ) ) [sid] => 66 )` and i just need to get my input data and also insert in the database.

Comment: @JemaiHamza I don't see any `$submission->first_name` element in your output..